# Difference between AXML and XAML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm new to Visual Studio Xamarin Cross-platform mobile development and I keep on searching about AXML I just can't find any tutorial for designing and applying an MVC approach.

I have a lot of questions regarding this actually. But i'll just leave this 3 here first.

1. What is their difference?
2. Can xaml designs be applied in axml?
3. How do I apply my css to axml files?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**1 -  What is their difference?**

AXML: Describe the UI for **only** Android apps. These are the same files used by Android native applications.

XAML: Specifies Xamarin.Forms layouts; these files describe a cross platform layout that each platform then renders in their native controls

**2 - Can xaml designs be applied in axml?**

Xaml designs cannot be directly copied into AXML (as they specify different controls) but they can be *ported* to AXML. Conceptually, xaml files describe how a UI should look on both platforms.

**3 - How do I apply my css to axml files?**

Cascading style sheets (CSS) are not applicable to Xaml as they describe how to style HTML. To style Xaml, look at the [styles API](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/) used by Xamarin.Forms

Comment: do you know any tutorials/demo on how to create designs/UI for cross-platform development, in AXML?

Comment: @JCBorlagdan AXML isn't cross-platform!

Comment: where is the part the post says AXML is a cross-platform?

Answer (score 5):

> What is their difference?

- AXML and XAML are two different XML specifications.
- AXML is just supported/available for Xamarin.Android.
- XAML is the way Xamarin Forms could standardize Cross Platform UI based on XML specification.
- If you are using native Xamarin Android you will do UI using axml, if using Forms then using XAML.

Reference from [What is the difference between Xaml & axml in Xamarin Technology](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Top-Xamarin-Interview-2eba0311#content)

> Can xaml designs be applied in axml?

**No**, since there is no direct translation between what Android can do and what Xamarin.Forms can.

> How do I apply my css to axml files?

You need to make your UI looks like CSS there is no direct way I know which can include your CSS to a AXML file.